# Error when trying to unit test AndroidViewModel using Koin

Tags: koin

I have a ViewModel that is covered with tests (was working fine). I had to inherit from `AndroidViewModel` since I needed access to a `Context`.

When I made the change, all my test are failing with the following error:

`Can't resolve Application instance. Please use androidContext() function in your KoinApplication configuration. org.koin.android.error.MissingAndroidContextException: Can't resolve Application instance. Please use androidContext() function in your KoinApplication configuration.`

My ViewModel definition in my Koin module:

```
viewModel { (formFactor: FormFactor, orientation: ProductOrientation) ->
    MyViewModel(
        androidApplication(),
        formFactor,
        orientation,
    )
}
```

My Koin initialisation:

```
startKoin {
    androidContext(this@MyMainApplication)
    fragmentFactory()
    modules(appModules)
}
```

The only change I introduces is adding `androidApplication()` argument to support the switch from `ViewModel` to `AndroidViewModel`

Comment: Let's address the root problem: why you need Context in your view-model?

Comment: @m0skit0 I don't think this is the problem, otherwise AndroidViewModel won't exist. The fact is we have it and we should be able to test it as well :)

Comment: @TareKKhoury did you use this for test `androidApplication()` or your production code?

Comment: @asadmahmood I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but please look at the code above where it shows how I'm using it